# how to solve the problem of downloading package "see"?

Tags: r, installation, package

I am trying to use the function ***check_model*** of the package ***performance*** in Rstudio. it's a really amazing function. However, it requires installing the ***see*** package.

I tried the following downloading methods and nothing have worked out :

*1- install.packages("see")*

*2- install.packages("see", repos = "https://easystats.r-universe.dev")*

*3- install_github("easystats/see")*

What would you guys suggest as a solution?

thanks.

Comment: I just tried downloading 'see'-package and it worked. Maybe you have to additionally install RTools or get the latest version of R?
RTools : https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: thanks a lot. yeah you are right I just update R to its latest version and it worked out well.